# mySQL, Find and Replace, with Find in one table and Replace in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have two tables, which aren't joined.

```
tbl_prod
cat_ids        prod_txt
1,2,3          some text

tbl_cat
category_id   cat_name
1             A
2             M
3             P
```

I need to perform a query which will update the contents of the 'cat_ids' column so the contents looks like this:

```
  tbl_prod
  cat_ids        prod_txt
  A,M,P          some text
```

Is this even possible in mySQL, or might I be better off creating a script to do this. Thanks

Comment: Normalize, normalize and once more normalize

Comment: These are essentially staging tables, the data has come from somewhere where I don't have control of the output, so normalizing isn't really an option here.

Comment: @Liam . . . You can normalize the data as a first step when you load the data and then not deal with comma delimited lists at all for the permanent storage of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct way:**

Normalize your tables. Storing foreign keys as csv column is really bad idea.

**Workaround:**

> I don't have control of the output, so normalizing isn't really an option here

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tc.cat_name ORDER BY tc.category_id) AS cat_ids,
       MAX(prod_txt) AS prod_txt
FROM tbl_prod AS tp
JOIN tbl_cat AS tc
  ON FIND_IN_SET(tc.category_id, tp.cat_ids) > 0
GROUP BY cat_ids;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33dcc1/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╗
║ cat_ids  ║ prod_txt  ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╣
║ A,M,P    ║ some text ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Update:

```
UPDATE tbl_prod t
join (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tc.cat_name ORDER BY tc.category_id) AS cat_ids_rep,
             MAX(tp.cat_ids) AS cat_ids 
     FROM tbl_prod AS tp
     JOIN tbl_cat AS tc
       ON FIND_IN_SET(tc.category_id, tp.cat_ids) > 0
      GROUP BY cat_ids
    ) AS sub
ON t.cat_ids = sub.cat_ids
SET t.cat_ids = sub.cat_ids_rep;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48a55/1/0)**</kbd>